# Bind Unbind onclick event not working with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having an issue with bind & unbind onClick listener using JQuery Ajax.

How to unbind on click event that it can't be clicked multiple times, but bind it if ajax fails. this is what I have tried so far.

```
$('#test').on('click', function (e) {  
 e.preventDefault();
 alert('clicked');
 $( "#test" ).off( "click");// works fine,remove on click listner
 // Ajax function
 // done()  // Do nothing.
 // error() // bind it again so it can be clicked.
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/khirad1996/4nLdvq9s/2/

Comment: i am just giving u alternative! declare a var count and increment it to 1 once first ajax done and check if count greater then one then only do ajax request otherwise disabled button

Comment: @MuhammadSami can I have a little demo? so i can understand it a bit clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the button while the call is happening, and re-enable if there is an error!

```js
const fakeAjax = time => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(Math.random() > .5), time))

const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', async function() {
  this.disabled = true;
  error = await fakeAjax(1000);
  this.disabled = error;
});
```

```html
<button>Ajax Call</button>
```

Comment: This will always disable the button for 1 sec regarless ajax call is successful or unsuccessfull, I just wanted it to be clickable if ajax return error

Comment: @Khirad2019 Yes this was just an illustration. I updated it to show how you might handle re-enabling the button.